# How to fix "clojure.test.check.generators never required" when exercising a function in clojurescript?

Tags: clojurescript, clojure.spec

In a Clojurescript environment when I run the following code I get the error `Var clojure.test.check.generators/simple-type-printable does not exist, clojure.test.check.generators never required`.

```clj
cljs.user=> (require '[clojure.spec.alpha :as spec])
nil
cljs.user=> (require '[clojure.spec.test.alpha :as stest])
nil
cljs.user=> (defn jp-a [n] n)
#'cljs.user/jp-a
cljs.user=> (spec/fdef jp-a :args (spec/cat :n int?))
cljs.user/jp-a
cljs.user=> (spec/exercise-fn `jp-a)
#object[Error Error: Var clojure.test.check.generators/simple-type-printable does not exist, clojure.test.check.generators neverrequired]
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is related to [this issue](https://clojure.atlassian.net/browse/CLJS-1792).

You only need to define `[org.clojure/test.check "0.10.0"]` (or a newer version) as a dependency in your `project.clj`.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually documented [here](https://clojure.org/guides/spec#_project_setup)

> spec generators rely on the Clojure property testing library `test.check`. However, this dependency is dynamically loaded and you can use the parts of spec other than gen, exercise, and testing without declaring `test.check` as a runtime dependency. When you wish to use these parts of spec (typically during testing), you will need to declare a dev dependency on test.check.
>
> In Leiningen add this to `project.clj`:
>
> ```
> :profiles {:dev {:dependencies [[org.clojure/test.check "0.9.0"]]}}
> ```